# extending react style prop with typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

What is the best way to extend the style prop in react to accept css variables as keys?

```
<button style={{ "--color": "red", ...props.style }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 render() {
   var style = {  "--color": "red", ...props.style } as React.CSSProperties;
   return (<button style={style} />);
  }
```

More in `React.CSSProperties` type definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8871b1e8938a1ed698ec8a88c77ee169294e45d4/types/react/index.d.ts#L974-L983

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add to the `CSSProperties` interface, which can be done pretty easily like so

```
declare module "react" {
  interface CSSProperties {
    /**
     * Add your custom properties here
     */
    "--x": string | number;
  }
}
```